# Access mysql running on localhost from minikube

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, database-connection, minikube

I am running some services in minikube and trying to connect to mysql running on localhost(127.0.0.1) on 3306 port.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43477742/9958058) and trying to create `service` and `Endpoints`. However, when I specify `127.0.0.1` as IP, it throws error as below:

`The Endpoints "mysql-service" is invalid: subsets[0].addresses[0].ip: Invalid value: "127.0.0.1": may not be in the loopback range (127.0.0.0/8)`

my deployment is like below:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql-service
spec:
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 1443
    targetPort: mysql

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: mysql-service
subsets:
  - addresses:
    - ip: 127.0.0.1
    ports:
    - name: mysql
      port: 3306
```

Please assist me to understand how can I connect to `mysql` db from `minikube`.

I have also tried replacing `127.0.0.1` with public IP of my computer(Don't know why though) and connection was timed out.

Any help or guide towards right direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 15):

As the OS and minikube `vm-driver` wasn't mentioned, I assume it is `--vm-driver=virtualbox` because it's probably most common case. If you use something different you need to adjust this solution according to your configuration.

#### Explanation:

`127.0.0.1` is a `localhost`(`lo0`) interface IP address. Nodes, Hosts and Pods have their own localhost interfaces and they are not connected to each other.

Your `mysql-server` is running on the Host machine and cannot be accessible using the `localhost` (or it's IP range) from inside a minikube cluster pod or from inside minikube vm.

#### Solution:

1. You should have a network between minikube VM and the host. Default NAT network in Virtualbox is not good for that, so it's better to create another host-only network. Let's [create](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-create-virtualbox-networks-with-the-host-network-manager/) additional host-only network in Virtualbox UI with the name `vmnet2` and IP range `192.168.77.1/24` . You don't need to enable DHCP for that network.
2. You have to configure mysql to listen on the interface vmnet2 or ip `192.168.77.1` which is by default used for the host machine. Check if it's accessible from the host:

```
mysql -h 192.168.77.1 -u root -p
```

3. To attach this network to minikube VM --host-only-cidr key should be used. Different type of `vm-driver` use different cli options for this purpose. Check the `minikube start --help` output. So, for `virtualbox` it will look like the following:

   ```
   minikube start --cpus 2 \
                  --memory 2048 \
                  --disk-size 20g \
                  --vm-driver virtualbox \
                  --network-plugin flannel \
                  --kubernetes-version v1.12.2 \
                  --host-only-cidr 192.168.77.1/24
   ```

   I wrote other most common cli options just for convenience.

   MinikubeVM will get the following IP address: `192.168.77.100` ([at least the first time.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53871053/how-to-completely-purge-minikube-config-or-reset-ip-back-to-192-168-99-100))
   You can check it using `minikube ssh` and then `ifconfig` commands.
4. Last part - we need to create a Service and Endpoint for it inside the `minikube` cluster:

```
kubectl apply -f mysql-service.yaml
```

Here is a content of the `mysql-service.yaml` file:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
   name: mysql-service
spec:
   type: ClusterIP
   ports:
   - protocol: TCP
     port: 3306
     targetPort: 3306
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: mysql-service
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 192.168.77.1
    ports:
      - port: 3306
```

5. Now we can use the `mysql-service` name and port `3306` inside any pod of this cluster as a destination point.

Answer (score 10):

According to [minikube's](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/host-access/) document, you can use `host.minikube.internal` to access your `localhost` if your `minikube's` version is higher than `v1.10`. you can use `minikube ssh` to confirm connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to your question but maybe it helps.

If the real problem is that you want to connect some service to the database it is possible to run the database (not the storage, containers might be stateless) inside Minikube. In this scenario, you will be able to use labels to match your database service with other services. We would use PersistentVolume, PersistenceVolumeClaim, and Secrets. This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aPzpsfQtlKY&list=LL&ab_channel=TechnoTownTechie) was really helpful for that.